# OpenCV binary adaptive threshold OCR

Tags: c++, opencv, binary-data, adaptive-threshold

I need to convert some images to binary for OCR.

Here are the functions I am using:

```
Mat binarize(Mat & Img, Mat& res, float blocksize, bool inverse)
{
    Img.convertTo(Img,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    CalcBlockMeanVariance(Img,res, blocksize, inverse);
    res=1.0-res;
    res=Img+res;
    if (inverse) {
        cv::threshold(res,res,0.85,1,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    } else {
        cv::threshold(res,res,0.85,1,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    }
    cv::resize(res,res,cv::Size(res.cols/2,res.rows/2));
    
    return res;
}
```

Where `CalcBlockMeanVariance`:

```
void CalcBlockMeanVariance(Mat& Img,Mat& Res,float blockSide, bool inverse) //21 blockSide - the parameter (set greater for larger font on image)
{
    Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I,CV_32FC1);
    Res=Mat::zeros(Img.rows/blockSide,Img.cols/blockSide,CV_32FC1);
    Mat inpaintmask;
    Mat patch;
    Mat smallImg;
    Scalar m,s;
    
    for(int i=0;i<Img.rows-blockSide;i+=blockSide)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<Img.cols-blockSide;j+=blockSide)
        {
            patch=I(Range(i,i+blockSide+1),Range(j,j+blockSide+1));
            cv::meanStdDev(patch,m,s);
            if(s[0]>0.01) // Thresholding parameter (set smaller for lower contrast image)
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=m[0];
            }else
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    cv::resize(I,smallImg,Res.size());
    
    if (inverse) {
        cv::threshold(Res,inpaintmask,0.02,1.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    } else {
        cv::threshold(Res,inpaintmask,0.02,1.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    }
    
    
    Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg,CV_8UC1,255);
    
    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask,CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, INPAINT_TELEA);
    
    cv::resize(inpainted,Res,Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    
}
```

When passing in `1` to `CalcBlockMeanVariance` as the `blockSide` I get this result, I have tried to raise the `blockSide` but it only results in worse results.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Can anyone suggest a different method for converting this image to binary as prep for OCR?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also take a look at my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122309/opencv-adaptive-threshold-ocr?rq=1

Comment: Your solution is actually the one I was trying to implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do your thresholding using [Otsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) method. You can apply it on your whole image or on the blocks of the image. I did the following steps:

- thresholding using `Otsu` method on desired input.
- `Closing` the result.

---

**Python Code**

```py
image = cv2.imread('image4.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # reading image
if image is None:
    print 'Can not find the image!'
    exit(-1)
# thresholding image using ostu method
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
# applying closing operation using ellipse kernel
N = 3
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (N, N))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# showing the result
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**Explanation**

In the first part I read the input image using `imread` and checked that the image opened correctly!.

```py
image = cv2.imread('image4.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # reading image
if image is None:
    print 'Can not find the image!'
    exit(-1)
```

Now thresholding the image with `otsu` method by feeding the `thresh` method with `THRESH_BINARY_INV | THRESH_OTSU` as its argument. The `otsu` method works base on an optimization problem finding the best value for thresholding. So I provided the range of possible value for the threshold value by giving it a lower bound by `0` and an upper bound by `255`.

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

And a closing operation is done for removing black holes in the image using an `Ellipse` kernel.

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (N, N))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

---

**Result**

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Can you please explain the close? Thanks.

Comment: @Constantine What difference does this make?`cv2.THRESH_OTSU` instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU`?

Comment: you can use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` instead of that! you will see that the foreground appears in black and background appears in white! it makes the output inverse if you use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`. run it with different options and you will see the results! it's the best practice ;)