# Reading numbers using PyTesseract

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I am trying to read numbers from images and cannot find a way to get it to work consistently (not all images have numbers). These are the images:

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]
[image: example 3]
[image: example 4]
[image: example 5]

(here is the link to the album in case the images are not working)

This is the command I'm using to run tesseract on the images: **pytesseract.image_to_string(image, timeout=2, config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')**. I have tried multiple configurations, but this seems to work best.

As far as preprocessing goes, this works the best:

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
    im_bw = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
```

This works for all images except the 3rd one. To solve the problem of lines in the 3rd image, i tried getting the edges with **cv2.Canny** and a pretty large threshold which works, but when drawing them back, even though it gets more than 95% of each number's edges, tesseract does not read them correctly.

I have also tried resizing the image, using **cv2.morphologyEx**, blurring it etc. I cannot find a way to get it to work for each case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.resize` has consistently worked for me with `INTER_CUBIC` interpolation.

Adding this last step to pre-processing would most likely solve your problem.

`im_bw_scaled = cv2.resize(im_bw, (0, 0), fx=4, fy=4, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`

You could play around with the scale. I have used '4' above.

EDIT:

The following code worked with your images very well, even special characters. Please try it out with the rest of your dataset. Scaling, OTSU and erosion was the best combination.

```
import cv2
import numpy
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "<path to tesseract.exe>"

# Page segmentation mode, PSM was changed to 6 since each page is a single uniform text block.
custom_config = r'--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'

# load the image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread("5.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Change all pixels to black, if they aren't white already (since all characters were white)
img[img != 255] = 0

# Scale it 10x
scaled = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Retained your bilateral filter
filtered = cv2.bilateralFilter(scaled, 11, 17, 17)

# Thresholded OTSU method
thresh = cv2.threshold(filtered, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Erode the image to bulk it up for tesseract
kernel = numpy.ones((5,5),numpy.uint8)
eroded = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 2)

pre_processed = eroded

# Feed the pre-processed image to tesseract and print the output.
ocr_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(pre_processed, config=custom_config)
if len(ocr_text) != 0:
    print(ocr_text)
else: print("No string detected")
```

Comment: Thanks! What threshold did you use?

Comment: Using the otsu method works well with a range (min and Max limits) of threshold values and letting the method find the best threshold. You will find a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23260699

Comment: Thanks! Using your code and adding a custom threshold at 230 worked for all my test cases.