# opencv binarize images with text

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need to binarize images with text.. It works very well but in some cases the output is empty (white image)

## code

```
/*
 *  Compile
 *  # g++ txtbin.cpp -o txtbin `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
 *
 *  Run
 *  # ./txtbin input.jpg output.png
 */

#include "string"
#include "fstream"
#include "/usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "/usr/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace boost;

void CalcBlockMeanVariance(Mat& Img, Mat& Res, float blockSide=21, float contrast=0.01){
    /*
     *  blockSide: set greater for larger fonts in image
     *  contrast: set smaller for lower contrast image
     */
    
    Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I, CV_32FC1);
    Res = Mat::zeros(Img.rows / blockSide, Img.cols / blockSide, CV_32FC1);
    Mat inpaintmask;
    Mat patch;
    Mat smallImg;
    Scalar m, s;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < Img.rows - blockSide; i += blockSide){
        for(int j = 0; j < Img.cols - blockSide; j += blockSide){
            patch = I(Range(i, i + blockSide + 1), Range(j, j + blockSide + 1));
            meanStdDev(patch, m, s);
            
            if(s[0] > contrast){
                Res.at<float>(i / blockSide, j / blockSide) = m[0];
            }
            else{
                Res.at<float>(i / blockSide, j / blockSide) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    resize(I, smallImg, Res.size());
    
    threshold(Res, inpaintmask, 0.02, 1.0, THRESH_BINARY);
    
    Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg, CV_8UC1, 255);
    
    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask, CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, INPAINT_TELEA);
    
    resize(inpainted, Res, Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
}

tuple<int, int, int, int> detect_text_box(string input, Mat& res, bool draw_contours=false){
    Mat large = imread(input);
    
    bool test_output = false;
    
    int
        top = large.rows,
        bottom = 0,
        left = large.cols,
        right = 0;
    
    int
        rect_bottom,
        rect_right;
    
    Mat rgb;
    // downsample and use it for processing
    pyrDown(large, rgb);
    Mat small;
    cvtColor(rgb, small, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // morphological gradient
    Mat grad;
    Mat morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    morphologyEx(small, grad, MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);
    // binarize
    Mat bw;
    threshold(grad, bw, 0.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    // connect horizontally oriented regions
    Mat connected;
    morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(9, 1));
    morphologyEx(bw, connected, MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel);
    // find contours
    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(bw.size(), CV_8UC1);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(connected, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    // filter contours
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0]){
        Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
        Mat maskROI(mask, rect);
        maskROI = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        // fill the contour
        drawContours(mask, contours, idx, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);
        // ratio of non-zero pixels in the filled region
        double r = (double)countNonZero(maskROI) / (rect.width * rect.height);
        
        // assume at least 45% of the area is filled if it contains text
        if (r > 0.45 && 
        (rect.height > 8 && rect.width > 8) // constraints on region size
        // these two conditions alone are not very robust. better to use something 
        //like the number of significant peaks in a horizontal projection as a third condition
        ){
            if(draw_contours){
                rectangle(res, Rect(rect.x * 2, rect.y * 2, rect.width * 2, rect.height * 2), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            }
            
            if(test_output){
                rectangle(rgb, rect, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            }
            
            if(rect.y < top){
                top = rect.y;
            }
            rect_bottom = rect.y + rect.height;
            if(rect_bottom > bottom){
                bottom = rect_bottom;
            }
            if(rect.x < left){
                left = rect.x;
            }
            rect_right = rect.x + rect.width;
            if(rect_right > right){
                right = rect_right;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(draw_contours){
        rectangle(res, Point(left * 2, top * 2), Point(right * 2, bottom * 2), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }
    
    if(test_output){
        rectangle(rgb, Point(left, top), Point(right, bottom), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        imwrite(string("test_text_contours.jpg"), rgb);
    }
    
    return make_tuple(left * 2, top * 2, (right - left) * 2, (bottom - top) * 2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    string input;
    string output = "output.png";
    
    int
        width = 0,
        height = 0;
    
    bool
        crop = false,
        draw = false;
    
    float margin = 0;
    
    //  Return error if arguments are missing
    if(argc < 3){
        cerr << "\nUsage: txtbin input [options] output\n\n"
            "Options:\n"
            "\t-w <number>          -- set max width (keeps aspect ratio)\n"
            "\t-h <number>          -- set max height (keeps aspect ratio)\n"
            "\t-c                   -- crop text content contour\n"
            "\t-m <number>          -- add margins (number in %)\n"
            "\t-d                   -- draw text content contours (debugging)\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    //  Parse arguments
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if(i == 1){
            input = string(argv[i]);
            
            //  Return error if input file is invalid
            ifstream stream(input.c_str());
            if(!stream.good()){
                cerr << "Error: Input file is invalid!" << endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-w"){
            width = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-h"){
            height = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-c"){
            crop = true;
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-m"){
            margin = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-d"){
            draw = true;
        }
        else if(i == argc - 1){
            output = string(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    
    Mat Img = imread(input, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat res;
    Img.convertTo(Img, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
    CalcBlockMeanVariance(Img, res);
    res = 1.0 - res;
    res = Img + res;
    threshold(res, res, 0.85, 1, THRESH_BINARY);
    
    int
        txt_x,
        txt_y,
        txt_width,
        txt_height;
    
    if(crop || draw){
        tie(txt_x, txt_y, txt_width, txt_height) = detect_text_box(input, res, draw);
    }
    
    if(crop){
        //res = res(Rect(txt_x, txt_y, txt_width, txt_height)).clone();
        res = res(Rect(txt_x, txt_y, txt_width, txt_height));
    }
    
    if(margin){
        int border = res.cols * margin / 100;
        copyMakeBorder(res, res, border, border, border, border, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    }
    
    float
        width_input = res.cols,
        height_input = res.rows;
    
    bool resized = false;
    
    //  Downscale image
    if(width > 0 && width_input > width){
        float scale = width_input / width;
        width_input /= scale;
        height_input /= scale;
        resized = true;
    }
    if(height > 0 && height_input > height){
        float scale = height_input / height;
        width_input /= scale;
        height_input /= scale;
        resized = true;
    }
    if(resized){
        resize(res, res, Size(round(width_input), round(height_input)));
    }
    
    imwrite(output, res * 255);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The text in the first image is very small compared to the text in the second image. I could see that this is a case of incorrect thresholding and it's just too small for your algorithm. Have you tried tweaking any thresholding values?

Comment: Other images where the text is even smaller the output isn't blank.. Its not me who have written the code so I hardly know where to tweak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok :)
Set `blockSide` smaller (7 for instance) it will give you result image as shown below. It depends on font size, smaller fonts need smaller block size, else text will be filtered out and you get empty image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "/usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void CalcBlockMeanVariance(Mat& Img,Mat& Res,float blockSide=9) // blockSide - the parameter (set greater for larger font on image)
{
    Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I,CV_32FC1);
    Res=Mat::zeros(Img.rows/blockSide,Img.cols/blockSide,CV_32FC1);
    Mat inpaintmask;
    Mat patch;
    Mat smallImg;
    Scalar m,s;

    for(int i=0;i<Img.rows-blockSide;i+=blockSide)
    {       
        for (int j=0;j<Img.cols-blockSide;j+=blockSide)
        {
            patch=I(Range(i,i+blockSide+1),Range(j,j+blockSide+1));
            cv::meanStdDev(patch,m,s);
            if(s[0]>0.01) // Thresholding parameter (set smaller for lower contrast image)
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=m[0];
            }else
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=0;
            }           
        }
    }

    cv::resize(I,smallImg,Res.size());

    cv::threshold(Res,inpaintmask,0.02,1.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg,CV_8UC1,255);

    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask,CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, INPAINT_TELEA);

    cv::resize(inpainted,Res,Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);

}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namedWindow("Img");
    namedWindow("Edges");
    //Mat Img=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\BookPage.JPG",0);
    Mat Img=imread("test2.jpg",0);
    Mat res;
    Img.convertTo(Img,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    CalcBlockMeanVariance(Img,res); 
    res=1.0-res;
    res=Img+res;
    imshow("Img",Img);
    cv::threshold(res,res,0.85,1,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::resize(res,res,cv::Size(res.cols/2,res.rows/2));
    imwrite("result.jpg",res*255);
    imshow("Edges",res);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a one size fits all? this is an automated service... its not possible to set individual settings for each image

Comment: You can normalize image size (width) and text will not vary its size too much, when standard setting should work for most of images.

Comment: Looks fine for me. May be you have enother threshold value :            if(s[0]>0.01) // Thresholding parameter (set smaller for lower contrast image)

Comment: Have you changed anyting when creating img3?? which version of opencv are you using?

Comment: Opencv 2.4 (installed using apt-get from repository). No, I did not changed anything except block size, also may be threshold value as I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm using `2.4.9.1`.. Is that also the version you are using? Have you only changed blockside to `7` with the above output?

Comment: Exact version is 2.4.8, for last version I've adjusted block side to 9. I've added full code I used to get the above results.

Comment: have copy pasted your code.. have added a new output file (result.jpg) but can't get the same output as you..

Comment: Then it looks like OpenCV's issue then.

Comment: hmm.. you have used the exact code you have added in your answer to generate the above 3 output images?

Comment: Yes, just copy and paste it without any changes (for last image I've set block size to 9, for previous two block side 7 worked fine).

Comment: the blockside.. Is that the height of the text or is it the thickness of the font?

Comment: Nothing of that, it is statistical measurement parameter, used to compute mean variance. It defines the parameter to separate objects with high variance, from background which usually have low variance. Variance measured in that block averaged, that's why if you'll set too large block, there will be large background peace and it will averaged with foreground variance, which will reduce mean variance, and such block will be filtered out.

Comment: Ok, so the lower the `blockside` the more is considered as objects in the image?

Comment: In rough approximation it may be seen as density of gradients in small region (block).

Comment: Could you please try the code I provided in my question and when running the program use the `-d` parameter.. It will draw boxes arround all text blocks.. Isn't it possible to analyse these areas and calculate the "best" blockside value?

Comment: Added the result. As I see the rectangles appears after binarization so, they can't be used for adjustment in direct way. But looks like it works with block side 9 quite good for given image dpi and scale.

Comment: have added some images where there are shadows.. either the text is completely gone in the binarized image or the image is all black

Comment: I know its not possible to make one solution which will solves them/it all :)

Comment: Yes, nothing works everywhere with everything, else it cost infinite amount of money.

Comment: If the paper is blue the page is blank :)

Comment: It may seem very strange fact, but black on black will also not work, as white on white.