# Subtracting double from Mat in OpenCV, Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, threshold

I am trying to implement the threshold method, made with OpenCV, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122309/opencv-adaptive-threshold-ocr?rq=1). It is written in C++, so I am trying to rewrite it for myself to Java, for Android Studio. In the code here there is a line:`res=1.0-res;`. "res" is Mat (OpenCV matrix, the same as: `Mat mat = new Mat();`). How can I subtract 1.0, which is 'double' format from res, which is 'Mat' format in Java?

Comment: Have you tried: `Core.subtract(new Scalar(1), res, res)`?

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I just changed it a bit: `Core.subtract(new MatOfDouble(1.0), res, res);`. From Scalar to MatOfDouble.

Comment: For some reason it does not let me to accept my own answer: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". Well, everyone will see it at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Miki, for helping to solve this. This is how it should be:

```
Core.subtract(new MatOfDouble(1.0), res, res);
```