# how to find the threshold value of any image to extract text from credit card image

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv

I am applying the threshold value manually

I am trying to extract exact information of credit card.

I attached the sample images.

how can in extract credit card numbers exactly.

[image: Image to analyze]

```
import re

import cStringIO
import urllib

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from noiselevel import estimate_noise
import pytesseract
oriimage="sh.png"
newimage = cv2.resize(oriimage,(583,327))
newimage = newimage[150:250, 0:600]
  # valid_image = newimage[150:250, 0:600]
cv2.imwrite("moon.tif",newimage)
 # filter=ImageFilter.UnsharpMask(6.0,269,0)
 #  im=Image.open("moon.tif")
 # i=im.filter(filter)
 # i.save("l3.tif")
a=Image.open("moon.tif")
inputt="moon.tif"
img = cv2.imread(inputt,0)

ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,120,254,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: Please attach input image and expected output ?

Comment: may now you able see the sample images

Comment: Here code in CPP, but it not so long, you can easily port it to python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122309/opencv-adaptive-threshold-ocr/22127181#22127181

Comment: Give us your input image so that we can see what can be done.

Comment: i added my input image.may you able to view

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adaptive Thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) to binarise the image. Adaptive thresholding automatically determines the threshold value for given part of an image based on its surroundings. One advantage is that you do not have to hardcode the threshold. Another and more important advantage is that it gives a reasonable binarisation even when there is uneven lighting in the image.

Answer (score 0):

i improve the accuracy by resize the cropped image.

```
cv2.resize(newimage,(583,150)
```