# How do you remove the unnecessary blackness from binary images (mainly caused by dark areas/noise)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am working on Images of Textbook pages such as questions and handwritten notes and want the binary image for that for few different tasks mainly the OCR. But the problem is that if an image is having a bit of shadow or the brightness level is not continuous, it gives me a lot of black area covering my text.

I used `from skimage.filters import try_all_threshold` on my images and found that some work well with certain kind of images, others dont. I can not use Local Thresholding where I have to change parameters based on different images because I want to automate the process of OCR.

```
img_path = DIR+str(11)+'.png'
sk_image = imread(img_path,as_gray=True)

fig,ax = try_all_threshold(sk_image,figsize=(20,15))
plt.savefig('threshold.jpeg',dpi=350)
```

[image]

**Why is this black area forming in the image  and how can I remove this?**?

Will a denoising filter such as `Bilateral` or `Gauss` would do? If not,please suggest some other technique?

Comment: Please always post your input image separately so others can use it to test. We do not want to have to crop your input from all the other images. Suggestion to use adaptive thresholding or division normalization before thresholding.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122309/opencv-adaptive-threshold-ocr/22127181#22127181

Comment: now sauvola adaptive binarization is the best for most cases, the fastest solutions is to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV using division normalization.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Smooth with Gaussian blur
- Divide gray image by smoothed image
- Apply unsharp masking to sharpen
- Apply Otsu threshold
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.filters as filters

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('math.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (95,95), 0)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)

# sharpen using unsharp masking
sharp = filters.unsharp_mask(division, radius=1.5, amount=1.5, multichannel=False, preserve_range=False)
sharp = (255*sharp).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# save results
cv2.imwrite('math_division.jpg',division)
cv2.imwrite('math_division_sharp.jpg',sharp)
cv2.imwrite('math_division_thresh.jpg',division)

# show results
cv2.imshow('smooth', smooth)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.imshow('sharp', sharp)  
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Division image:

[image]

Sharpened image:

[image]

Thresholded image:

[image]

Comment: But this uses lot of Manual tuining. If I want to run an OCr for thousands of images, it's not a FIT for ALL use cases? no? Like the Gaussian Filter's param and others.

Comment: Yes, it could work, since the gaussian is a large value. Try it for a variety of images and see.

Comment: Okay. Will try to do that. Thanks. Any other suggestions? I'm basically doing this for OCR.